# Why "How to filter messages with specific emoji in the subject in Gmail?" is a duplicate of question asking how to detect any animated emoji?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How to filter messages with specific emoji in the subject in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/164302/how-to-filter-messages-with-specific-emoji-in-the-subject-in-gmail) which got closed as duplicate of far wider [How to filter messages with animated emoji in the subject in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89119/how-to-filter-messages-with-animated-emoji-in-the-subject-in-gmail)

The supposed duplicate has only workaround, not an actual answer. It is entirely possible that filtering on specific emoji can work, even if far more generic task of filtering on emoji subclass is impossible.

Why it got closed? Can I reopen it?

Comment: Please read [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @Rubén I have read it and as this answer ask about different things and inability to do one task does not imply at all than other one is impossible.

Comment: The referred article include directions about what to do when to reopen a question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks, I missed this. I added also comment, though I am well aware than chance for reopening even clearly incorrectly closed questions are nonexistent.